# What is the AXMakeProcessTrusted() equivalent on Mac OS 10.7+

Tags: macos, cocoa, security, accessibility

I need to track key presses in my App preferably without the user having to manually Enable Access to Assistive Devices and expose his system to other risks.

AXMakeProcessTrusted was an elegant solution to this in MacOS Tiger. But after tinkering around for days with this thing, I realised it hardly even works anymore. Couldn't find a newer approach to making processes trusted in Apple's Docs.

Anyone has a clue as to what would be the most elegant way to accomplish this?

Comment: Sounds like you're attempting to write a key logger or other spy ware..

Comment: I wish I was that smart.

Comment: Do you need to listen for key presses for you app only or globally?

Comment: Global events. I'm using addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask with keyboard event masks.

Comment: Did you figure this out, i dont need to add global events, but i just need accessibility so i can focus another application on user click.